# Generate random edge in a networkx DiGraph

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I have an `nx.DiGraph` object with a 1000000 nodes and 1500000 edges. The graph is bipartite and it is made like A->T->A where A are number bigger than 99602440 and T are smaller number. Approximately there are the same number of T and A.

I want to generate another graph with the same number of nodes but random edges. the edge should be generated by extracting from the in and out-degree distribution of the original graph.

This is the code I produced:

```
G=nx.read_weighted_edgelist("C:/Users/uccio/Desktop/tesi2/mygraphUpTo_2011_5_13", create_using=nx.DiGraph,nodetype=int)
#my original graph

def cumul(sort): #create cumulative frequencies
    ind=[]
    val=[]
    c=0
    for i, j in sort:
        ind.append(i)
        c+=j
        val.append(c)
    return ind, val


def exCum(cum_index, cum_value, sumtot): #binary search in the cumulative
    coin=int(random.randint(0,sumtot)) #extract random value
    val=np.searchsorted(cum_value,coin,side="left")
    return cum_index[val] #return key of the dictionary of cumulated frequencies
    
    


distin={} #dictionary of in-degree frequencies
distout={} #dictionary of out-degree frequencies
for f in G.nodes():
    if f<99602440:
        x=G.in_degree(f)
        y=G.out_degree(f)
        if x in distin:
            distin[x]+=1
        else:
            distin[x]=1
        if y in distout:
            distout[y]+=1
        else:
            distout[y]=1
sort_in=sorted(distin.items()) #ordered to do binary search in the dict
sort_out=sorted(distout.items())

cumin_index, cumin_val= cumul(sort_in) #cumulative value todo binary search in
cumout_index, cumout_val= cumul(sort_out)
sumtot_in=sum(distin.values())
sumtot_out=sum(distout.values())

test=nx.DiGraph()
test.add_nodes_from(G.nodes()) #my new graph
trans=[] #extracted T from the graph
add=[] #extracted A from the graph
for i in test.nodes():
     if i<99602440:
         trans.append(i)
     else:
         add.append(i)

for t in trans:
    
    ind=exCum(cumin_index, cumin_val, sumtot_in) #binary search return the key of the dictionary
    outd=exCum(cumout_index, cumout_val, sumtot_out)
    extin=list(random.choice(add,ind)) #choose random nodes from A to use as input
#it uses ind to choose how many A->T should exist
    extout=list(random.choice(add,outd)) #choose random nodes from A to use as output
#it uses ind to choose how many T->A should exist
    for inv in extin:
        test.add_weighted_edges_from([(inv,t,0)]) #creates the edges A->T for that T                
    for outv in extout:
        test.add_weighted_edges_from([(t,outv,0)])  #creates the edges T->A for that T
```

The code works but the last part (from `for t in trans:`) takes a long time (surely up to 5 hours but I went to bed while the computer was working so it could be more).
Is there a way to make everything faster?

Comment: It's probably faster to use networkx in-built `double_edge_swap` (swapping edge endpoints shuffles a graph while preserving the degree sequence). Documentation [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.swap.double_edge_swap.html).

Comment: Ok I'll try thanks